# Crash on accessing reference to string

Tags: c++, reference

This code crashes at the cout line.  Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class myclass {
   const string& m_str;

public:
   myclass(string s) : m_str(s) {}
   const string& getString() const { return m_str; }
};

int main () {
   const string str("honey");
   myclass mc(str);
   cout << mc.getString() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `myclass` constructor is taking a string by value which makes it a temporary. You're then binding this temporary to the `m_str` member. As soo as the constructor exits your member reference becomes invalid. Instead: `myclass(const string& s) : m_str(s) {}`

Even so that may not be a good idea. Generally speaking using references as members *can* be dangerous because you have to be very clear about lifetime semantics. You should consider just storing the string by value in your class unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

Comment: I was just playing with references really to try to understand what is going on. If the string was BIG it could be a good way to go I suppose.